In OAuth 2.0 what if the attacker uses the redirect uri to send the authorization code before the client to get the access token?
What happens if the attacker is viewing the network data and manages to view the authorization code and then uses it to get the access token before the actual client.
Would the attacker then be able to get the access token?
How is this prevented in OAuth?

PCKE address this case in hear
